# Determine if two collections share at least one element

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to determine if a collection contains at least one element from another collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Any().

```
var listA = new List<int>();
var listB = new List<int>();

bool hasCommonItem = listA.Any(i => listB.Contains(i));
```

Moreover, you can write an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) implementation to pass it as a parameter to the Contains() if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Sure there is.

```
var sourceCollection = GetSourceCollection();
var otherCollection = GetAnotherCollection();

var hasAtLeastOne = sourceCollection.Intersect(sourceCollection).Any();
```

I assumed your collections are of the same type: `IEnumerable<T>` with the same `T` generic parameter.

It's gonna load whole `sourceCollection` first, and then fetch one element at a time from `otherCollection` until first common one is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
col1.Any(x => col2.Any(y => x==y));
```